# ssh server when port forwarding not available

Tags: networking, ssh

My mother's laptop can be connected to many different networks, and I am unable to configure proper port forwarding on them all.

I would still like to have remote access to help her when she needs it.

Is there a way to configure her computer so that I can ssh into it, no matter the network she is on? I can use an external server to act as bridge, if that would be helpful.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The answer is something called reverse ssh tunelling.

Explanations on how it works and how to do it can be found on another question on stack exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work